# Gatby console warning There are conflicting field types in your data.' when using createPage twice on the same query

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I've made an query with `createPages` and using the `result.data` with `createPage` twice:

1. for each page node
2. for listpages which contains multiple excerpts per page, build out of the page nodes.

Now I'm getting a warning that says,

> warn There are conflicting field types in your data. If you have explicitly defined a type for those fields, you can safely ignore this warning message. Otherwise, Gatsby will omit those fields from the GraphQL schema.

So, my question is,

- What does this actually mean?
- What is explicitly defining a type for those fields?
- Can I safely ignore this?

This is my stripped down *gatby-node.js* file

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { slash } = require(`gatsby-core-utils`)

// Gatsby API “createPages”.
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allWordpressPost {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            path
            status
            template
            format
            title
            content
            excerpt
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  // Check for any errors
  if (result.errors) {
    throw new Error(result.errors)
  }

  // Access query results via object destructuring
  const { allWordpressPost } = result.data

  // create pages for each post node.
  const postTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/Post.js`)
  allWordpressPost.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/post${edge.node.path}`,
      component: slash(postTemplate),
      context: { data: edge.node },
    })
  })

  //create summary pages for post nodes.
  const blogTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/Blog.js`)
  const posts = allWordpressPost.edges //All posts
  const postPerPage = 3 //Post excerpts per page
  const pages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postPerPage) // Number of pages needed
  Array.from({ length: pages }).forEach((edge, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: index === 0 ? "/blog/" : `/blog/${index + 1}`, //route based on index
      component: slash(blogTemplate),
      context: {
        data: posts.slice(
          index * postPerPage,
          index * postPerPage + postPerPage
        ),
        pages,
        currentPage: index + 1,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I used the same key (`data: posts.slice( //...`) on both context objects (blog posts and the paginated blog summary) and changed one to something different (`content: posts.slice( //...`).